# Entity Framework mapping multiple entities by GUID

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, one-to-many

I have some classes

```cs
public class Class1
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Class1Id { get; set; }
    public List<MediaSet> MediaSet { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Class2Id { get; set; }
    public List<MediaSet> MediaSet { get; set; }
}

public class MediaSet
{
    [Key]
    public int MediaSetId { get; set; }
    public Guid ObjectId { get; set; }
    public List<Media> Media { get; set; }
}

public enum MediaType { Photo, Video }

public class Media
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid MediaId { get; set; }
    public MediaType MediaType { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int MediaSetId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MediaSetId")]
    public MediaSet MediaSet { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map class MediaSet to Class1 and Class2 via single property property ObjectId, how can I do this?
So that later I could just execute the following queries

```cs
var classes1WithMediaSet = MyDbContext.Classes1.Include(x => x.MediaSet).ToList();
var classes2WithMediaSet = MyDbContext.Classes2.Include(x => x.MediaSet).ToList();
```

Comment: Have you thought about `Fluent API`?

Comment: Yes, I use Fluent API, but not have many experience